# Can I travel to Dominican Republic, on a valid US B2 Visa with an Indian Passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, dominican-republic

I am an Indian Citizen, with a Valid US B1/B2 Visa and a previous travel history to USA. I read on Wikipedia that "if you can travel or reside in US" you can enter Dominican republic too.

Can I show my B1/B2 Visa to enter Dominican for 2 days of weekend trip from India ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a valid visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Romania, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State traveling as tourists for a maximum stay of 90 days.